# Entity Framework Core 2 - Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to have a model with two references to another model.

I have researched this error, but have seen suggestions relating to previous .Net Core versions.

Below is the model

```
public class Match
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime MatchDateTime
    { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public int HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int HomeTeamID { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamID { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("HomeTeamID")]
    public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AwayTeamID")]
    public Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
}
```

Upon running the migration, i get this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Matches_Teams_AwayTeamID' on table 'Matches' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: Can you provide us `OnModelCreating` method contents (since you're stated using Code First migrations)? I think you have problem in `modelBuilder.Entity<Match>` relationship which may declared more than once, causing multiple cycles or cascade paths.

Comment: Set your fk onelete to restrict instead of cascade

Comment: The error isn't related to any .Net version, it's a SQL Server error that pretty clearly tells you shat's wrong. The two FKs to `Team` can't both have cascaded delete.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: I have no code in my OnModelCreating() function

Comment: @Mardoxx: I am not sure what DataAnnotation I should use to accomplish that.

Comment: @GertArnold: Thank you for indiciating the obvious. I am asking how to correct this issue from the Code First Model code, such that SQL will not have the issue.

Comment: its similar to one - many relation, i don't know why you don't just specify a type column in the Team Model, and instead of two props in the match model, use an `ICollection<Team> Team;`

Comment: @sh.alawneh It is sort of a hyrbrid of one-many and two-many. Meaning, one Match must have two teams related to it. One Team entity, can only relate to one match at a time. I have already setup up the collection reference in the Team entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So..The solution was simple really.

I made the Foreign Key IDs nullable. I am not sure if making both nullable was 'required'

See the code below:

```
public class Match
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public DateTime MatchDateTime
{ get; set; }
public int LocationID { get; set; }
public int GroupID { get; set; }
public int HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
public int AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
public int? HomeTeamID { get; set; }
public int? AwayTeamID { get; set; }
public Location Location { get; set; }
public Group Group { get; set; }

[Required]
[ForeignKey("HomeTeamID")]
public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("AwayTeamID")]
public Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: What if you Require nullable, then?

Answer (score 2):

When you run `Add-Migration`, it will generate migration file similar to the below code.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
name: "Match",
columns: table => new
{
    ID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
    AwayTeamID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
    AwayTeamScore = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
    GroupID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
    HomeTeamID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
    HomeTeamScore = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
    LocationID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
    MatchDateTime = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false)
},
constraints: table =>
{
    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Match", x => x.ID);
    table.ForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Match_Team_AwayTeamID",
        column: x => x.AwayTeamID,
        principalTable: "Team",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    table.ForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Match_Team_HomeTeamID",
        column: x => x.HomeTeamID,
        principalTable: "Team",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
});
```

Set `ReferentialAction.NoAction` for `FK_Match_Team_HomeTeamID`.